# Always getting MalformedPolicyDocument error while trying to create IAM role using Boto3

Tags: json, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, boto3

I am using json from the default AWS policy AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

While this is the code i'm using to create the role:

```
def create_lambda_role():
205     try:
206         iam = boto3.client('iam')
207 
208         lambda_permissions_json = ''
209         with open('lambda/lambda_permissions.json', 'r') as thefile:
210             lambda_permissions_json = thefile.read()
211 
212         iam.create_role(
213             RoleName='lambda_basic_execution',
214             AssumeRolePolicyDocument=str(lambda_permissions_json)
215         )
216     except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
217         print e.response['Error']['Code']
218         return False
219 
220     return True
```

But it always returns a MalformattedPolicyDocument error and I can't for the life of me see why.

Comment: What is the content of this file? lambda_permissions.json

Comment: The json at the top is the content of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` parameter expects a JSON trust policy describing who can assume this role.  You are providing a policy that is describing which resources this role will have access to.

For more information on trust policies, see [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) but the assume role policy should look something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"},
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
}
```

This is probably not what you want but the point is that the trust policy is describing who is allowed to assume this role, not what the role has access to.

You could then create another policy that contains your resource permissions and attach that policy to your new role.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed but with the service changed to "lambda.amazonaws.com".